# debugging java functions via serverless-framework invoke local

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, debugging, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am working on a project using the serverless framework with code written in Java and deployed on AWS.  I am able to deploy the lambda functions to AWS and I am also able to use the "serverless invoke local" command to run them locally.

What I haven't figured out is how to attach to and debug this locally running function.  I don't see any promising command line options, and the java invocation didn't make use of the $JAVA_OPTS environment variable to configure it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your code locally using the [`serverless-offline`](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline) plugin

Supply your JDWP agent string via the  environment variable [`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/troubleshoot/environment-variables-and-system-properties.html#GUID-BE6E7B7F-A4BE-45C0-9078-AA8A66754B97). Be sure to set `suspend=y`, to ensure you can connect your debugger before the function finishes executing. There are lots of ways of doing this — I suggest using the [`serverless-dotenv`](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-dotenv) plugin.

For example:

```
cat >> .serverless/.env < EOF
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:3888
EOF

sls offline --stage local --debug=*
```

Using `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` should work in AWS, according to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-modify.html)... But your mileage may vary with tunneling etc.